# Wordpress - get previous value of a php variable after an action hook (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a wordpress plugin and it regards to comparing the previous value of a sku from some product to the updated sku:

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'product_changes_logged', 10, 1);// triggers the product_changes_logged function when the product is updated (let assume it was sku changing)

function product_changes_logged($product_id) {

    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $sku = $product->get_sku();//trying to get previous sku

}
```

The code above takes the sku after the changing occurs, but I'd like to get the before sku as soon as a product changing is requested (before sku changes) I could list all skus before the event get triggered and the compare but it's not a practice. If some of you know the list of events and variable names in woocommerce it'd help me a lot.

Comment: This hook executes at the very end of the `update` method, https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php#L201 I see that method do `$changes = $product->get_changes();` at the start, you could try that - although I kinda doubt it will _still_ get you the changes, after the product has been updated already, so that might not work. You might need to find a different hook then.

Comment: how can i check all hooks

Comment: There's lists available, such as https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html

Comment: I found out the hook I wanted, it's woocommerce_admin_process_product_object or woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object

Comment: @CBroe do you know the hook regarding a new order? (not a fake new order created by admin panel) I'm in three days trying to find this but I just can get the hook triggered when a fake new order is created.